# Help hiding initial text after boot

Tags: boot, raspbian-stretch

I'm working on a Raspi Zero W emulating an apple IIgs. I want to hide all messages and text, the only visible thing should be the emulator itself. Already hid the startup text, but after booting, and just before autostart the emulator, it shows the Raspbian Version and the start of the emulator text.
- I'm running RetroPie 4.4 with the latest updates to stretch.
- Already followed the "silent" boot options, just need to hide the text after booting.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Attached is an image of the text I want to hide.[image]